# How to access the Intel XDK api from a remote website

Tags: intel-xdk

I am opening a remote url in a child window like this:

```
intel.xdk.device.showRemoteSite('http//my.site', 0, 0, 24, 24);
```

Apparently it is possible for me to use 'mainViewExecute' in javascript in my remote site code to execute api methods on the main form eg.

```
intel.xdk.device.mainViewExecute('intel.xdk.notification.beep(1);');
```

But the 'intel' object is undefined so it seems I am missing some reference etc. or is it not possible to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>` added to your `index.html`, you dont need the actual file, the Intel XDK emulator and build will automatically include it, you just need to add a script tag to `index.html`

Comment: In the index.html of my XDK project I do have reference to intelxdk.js but my remote site (completely separate to the xdk project) does not have access to the intel objects when opened in a child window

Comment: I just noticed there was a bug, `intelxdk.js` in remote site is not working, you can use this as a work around, add this script tag to the remote site and it will work: `<script src="http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/appmobi.js"></script>`, let me know if u have problems I will send you sample code.

Comment: Krisrak - I have done a fair amount of testing and the 'mainViewExecute' method simply doesn't seem to work in the new XDK version. What I am seeing has been confirmed on the XDK forum aswell. Do you perhaps have any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure whose comment was made first yesterday. Anyway I tried your suggestion with using <script src="http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/appmobi.js"></script>
and managed to get it working with some tweaks. I agree that it looks like a bug and I have logged on the XDK forum, along with my working code:  https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=5075

Comment: ok thanks, i work on the XDK team, I have logged it internally